# d3js server side rendering how to insert a script for client execution

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, d3.js, svg

I am exploring d3js svg creation on the server side using nodeJS, express-js and jsdom.  I am able to create svg graphs which will show up on the browser properly.  Now, I wanted to add some event interaction code to the graphic, which should get executed on the client (browser).  If I add event code in the jsdom.env(...), it is going to be valid only in jsdom.  But when I send the final markup to browser, this event code is not available.  How to solve this problem?

My code reproduced below is in two logical parts.

**part 1:**
ExpressJS handling code that handles an incoming request, by loading html from filesystem, and has necessary glue code to construct jsdom env.

```
  8 var w = 500, h=200;
  9 app.get('/env', function(req, res) {
 10   jsdom.env({
 11     file: './hello.html',
 12     src: foo,
 13     done: function(err, window) {
 14       var $ = window.$;
 15       window.d3 = d3.select(window.document);
 16       var dataset = [ 5, 10, 13, 19, 21, 25, 22, 18, 15, 13,
 17                 11, 12, 15, 20, 18, 17, 16, 18, 23, 25 ];
 18 
 19       var svg = window.d3.select('body')
 20         .append('svg')
 21         .attr('width', w)
 22         .attr('height', h);
 23       bar(svg, dataset);
 24       res.end(window.document.documentElement.outerHTML);
 25     }
 26   });
 27 });
 28 
 29 app.listen(3111);
```

**part2**
The function bar(...) which uses d3js to actually create a bar chart.

```
54 function bar(svg, data) {
55   var barPadding =1;
56   svg.selectAll("rect")
57       .data(data)
58       .enter()
59       .append("rect")
60       .attr('height', function(d){
61           var barHeight = d*4 + "px";
62           return barHeight;
63        })
64       .attr('width', w/data.length - barPadding)
65       .attr('x', function(d,i) { return i* w/data.length; })
66       .attr('y', function(d) { return h-d*4; })
67       .attr('fill', function(d) { return "rgb(0,0," + (d*10) + ")"; })
68       .on('mouseover', function() {
69         d3.select(this)
70           alert('this:'+ this);
71       }); 
72 
      ...
95    return svg;
96 }
```

Now the code for on('mouseover', ...), which is available in jsdom, won't appear, when I try to serialize the markup and send to browser.

Is there a way, I can insert this script into svg and have it available in browser for client execution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just load it in as a string:

```
window.d3.select('body')
  .append('script')
  .text("d3.selectAll('rect').on('mouseover', function() { alert(this); });")
```

Note, for that to work you'll need to `<script src=` `d3` in your html as well.